# relative change in probabilities - a complete manipulation of data?!

Tags: probability, statistics

We are learning about relative vs. absolute change in my statistics course. I understand the math of the relative chance formula, but I cannot understand when there is a proper use for it. I can't seem to get an explanation that makes it comprehensible to me why/when you would use it to make an argument for something.

The example in our class was talking about cell phone ownership and probability of depression. The article we used as background used relative change to make their claims. To me, this seems irresponsible and a complete manipulation of the data.

Can someone please fill me in on what I might be misunderstanding? Or, agree with me and explain why relative change exists and what its purpose is?

Thank you!

Comment: Relative change sets a scale. For big/small initial quantities, moderate changes lead to big/small absolute changes which can be misleading. (Consider for example a million dollars in the grand scheme of the US federal government's annual budget). Relative change in probability is a bit more dangerous because probability already has a fixed scale.

Comment: Well, we don't have your example in hand so we can't comment on that.  But in dealing with populations of unknown size, it makes no sense to speak of absolute change.  If I say "a thousand people in my sample started smoking in the last year"  it makes a huge difference if my sample is "people in my small town" or "everyone in the United States".  But percent difference has meaning regardless of size.